# can't use inspector with appium 1.6.0

Tags: ios, automation, appium, inspector

i recently installed XCode 8 beta 5.
Appium 1.6.0 beta on my MAC 10.11.6
now after reading all the forums and making the Appium start and launch my app, i can't find how to launch my inspector and find elements in my app with this Appium 1.6.0 beta.
how do we launch inspector with appium 1.6.0 beta? 
if we can't , how can we find xpath or find elements ??

Comment: post the error log please.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to make use of both appium versions(apium1.6.X server and appium1.5.3 GUI) and this solutions works for both android and IOS. Please find the steps below,

- launch the appium (1.6 or above) from the command prompt/terminal
- Open the appium 1.5.3 GUI and fill in all required settings, **BUT DONOT HIT LAUNCH**

  1. AppPath,
  2. package
  3. Automation Name,
  4. Platform version - even if we couldn't find in drop down edit it,
  5. Device Name
- then click on the inspector icon on the GUI.

This should open appium inspector using Appium server.

*Note: Provide automation name as "Appium" for android!

Comment: Perfect!  Working GUI in 1.5.3 with app is running from 1.6 appium version

Comment: In the Developer Settings of the 1.5.3 App, you can set your external Appium Package to the 1.6.3 Appium installation. This will run 1.6.3 when you hit Launch on the app. For example, if you installed Appium via NPM then you can set the external Appium package from the default value to /usr/local/bin/appium.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to build and deploy your application using XCode 8 or above, or even using the Appium GUI try this. Once it is is open within the iOS Simulator you can use the XCode provided Accessibility Inspector.

XCode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector

I find that this is much faster that the Appium Inspector and gives me the element names that are needed. I try to stay away from using Xpath, so this works great for me. But if Xpaths are definitely needed, I have been using getPageSource() and parsing the xml for elements that I am looking for, that seems to do the trick for me.

Attached is a screenshot that shows the type of information that can be obtained from the Accessibility Inspector.[Accessibility Inspector Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNFfG.png)

Answer (score 0):

Though Appium 1.6.0-beta1 released, it's command tools not GUI appium.

Comment: what do you mean? how can I capture elements?

Comment: check @Andrew Rymar Answer. He is right about using inspector with Appium 1.6

Answer (score 0):

For now you should use Appium 1.5 GUI app from appium.io.

If you are going to launch your tests against iOS 10 you will need to modify your xpath locators: https://github.com/chenchaoyi/macaca-appium#run-test-with-xcuitest

But if your target OS <= iOS9 it is OK to stay with old good xpaths got from Appium 1.5 GUI.

Comment: The v. 1.5 inspector is failing for me. Apparently it is overriding the "automationName" set for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently appium 1.6 is not available in GUI to inspect the elements, there is workaround you can get the elements.

Try this :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BgkVp0v3BM

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, you can also use this github project [Appium-iOS-Inspector](https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector) to inspect iOS view elements with new Appium 1.6

**Steps to use:**

1. Launch appium server from terminal by running "appium" command
2. Run the app on simulator or device from xcode or from terminal's "arc" command.
3. Download as zip or clone the [Appium-iOS-Inspector](https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector).
4. Open the **Appium-iOS-Inspector/iOS Inspector.html** file in any browser. This will show you the device view will complete elements tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've been finding this for a week.